# how to compare two audio signals with Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two audio signas that I want to compare using Matlab, my problem is that I can hear the difference between them loud and clear, but when use the function `pwelch` to compare their PSD ,I don't see much difference between them,any idea how can I compare them with a different methode ! thanks in advance ! 
PS:   1.  I already ask the quesiton in DSP.stackexchange but had no answer!
      2. I'm not asking for codes, that'S why I didn't put mine !

**UPDATE**

after the answer of @Bas Swinckels here the code par that I'm using the result and I still can't see a way that the describ this  ?

```
  clear;
clc;
[x0,Fs] = audioread('Nonoise.wav');
x0 = x0(:,1);
[Y0,G] = pwelch(x0,hamming(512));
plot(G,10*log10(Y0));
grid on 

[x50,Fs] = audioread('50% noise.wav');
x50 = x50(:,1);
[Y50,G] = pwelch(x50,hamming(512));
hold on ;
plot(G,10*log10(Y50),'r');


[x100,Fs] = audioread('100% noisy.wav');
x100 = x100(:,1);
[Y100,G] = pwelch(x100,hamming(512));
hold on ;
plot(G,10*log10(Y100),'g');

%% spectrogram  
spectrogram(x0,hann(64),32,64,Fs)
figure();
spectrogram(x50,hann(64),32,64,Fs)
figure();
spectrogram(x100,hann(64),32,64,Fs)
```

and here are the result :

[image: pwelch result]

[image: no noise or no effect]

[image: 50 percent]

[image: 100 percent noisy]

can anybody tell me how does the noise or the effect that I'm adding to the source influences my spectrum ?

Comment: Do the signals have exactly the same time reference and duration? Can't you just subtract them?

Comment: I cut them to get the same duration, how would the subtracting make a sense ?

Comment: Well, to see a _difference_ you subtract. However, that will work only if the signals are perfectly aligned (same time origin)

Comment: I can't make sure that,  this will always be the case !

Comment: could the SNR be a way to compare them, since the sound has the same source but field changes ?

Comment: Can you post some example signals somewhere online?

Comment: @LuisMendo i read somewhere that subtracting is  so called `Null test`. So in what cases performing this null test is acceptable, mean conditions like the signals should be time aligned,same fs,and what other conditions ??

Comment: @nmxprime I guess time alignment and same sample frequency should be enough. Maybe also normalize signals to the amplitude, depending on whether having different amplitudes is significant or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to plot a [spectrogram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) of both signals like so:

```
spectrogram(x, hann(nfft), nfft/2, nfft, fsample)
```

When you calculate a PSD with `pwelch`, you only get the average spectrum and you lose all temporal information: it will not show you if a signal is louder at the beginning or at the end. Calculating a spectrogram is also pretty similar to what your ears perceive, they measure a sort of spectrum as a function of time. So if you can hear the difference, it should show up as a difference in the spectrogram with enough SNR.

When you make a spectrogram, you should try to play with the frequency and temporal resolution, since they follow some sort of Heisenberg law. Making the FFT window short (by chosing a small `nfft`) will give you good temporal resolution, but worse frequency resolution, and the other way around.

Comment: sorry, but  shouldn't I calculate the PSD when I'm working with stochastic signals ? and by the spectrogram do almost the same  as pwelch ! at least when I see the result ok its 3d but It seem to me to be the same !

Comment: To get a statistically correct estimate of the spectrum, you should indeed use `pwelch` type periodograms. But in this way, you lose all temporal information. Nothing is forbidding you to make a spectrogram, which are basically the individual spectra over which `pwelch` takes the average. By playing with the frequency and temporal resolution of the spectrogram, you could even do a limited number of averages per time-bin. But it depends on how much data you have, usually you have to do a trade-off between frequency and time resolution. Just try it, in the worst case it is too noisy ...

Comment: well I did it again but I still  can't see any difference !

Comment: Did you try various values for `nfft`? I would typically try with many different powers of 2.